# Problem to extract the href link from the soup find result

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to get the link from the website **https://www.lianjia.com/city/** inside the first search province. From the first province, I want to get the link for the cities to belong to this province, I find all the **li** tags with the **href** link by `print(t)`, but when I try to extract the link by `t.get('href')`, it return nothing, what is the problem with the below code, can someone please help?

```
url1 = 'https://www.lianjia.com/city/'
req1 = requests.get(url1)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(req1.content, 'html.parser')
part = soup1.findAll("div",{"class":"city_province"})
for t in part[0].find_all('li'):
    print(t)
    print(t.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`li` tag has no `href` attribute. You have to get all anchors to get the `href`.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.lianjia.com/city/').content, 'html.parser')
provinces = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "city_province"})
anchors = [[a["href"] for a in p.find_all("a")] for p in provinces]

for province_urls in anchors:
    print(province_urls)
```

Output:

```
['https://aq.lianjia.com/', 'https://cz.fang.lianjia.com/', 'https://hf.lianjia.com/', 'https://mas.lianjia.com/', 'https://wuhu.lianjia.com/']
['https://bj.lianjia.com/']
['https://cq.lianjia.com/']
['https://fz.lianjia.com/', 'https://quanzhou.lianjia.com/', 'https://xm.lianjia.com/', 'https://zhangzhou.lianjia.com/']
and so on...
```